# MySQL query to fetch data that matches data in another table

Tags: mysql

So we have two tables:

Tabl№1

```
| Ads | Date  |
| :--------- | :-------------- |
| Buy Auto    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Wanted equipment    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Work    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Buy water    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
```

Tabl№2

```
| Zag |
| :--------- |
| auto    |
| equipment    |
```

How to write a query to MySQL table Tabl№1 to get only the data that matches the condition:

1. To take only those rows from the 'Ads' column of Tabl№1 that match the data from the 'Zag' column from TablNo2

As a result, it should receive only such data from Tabl№1:

```
| Ads | Date  |
| :--------- | :-------------- |
| Buy Auto    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
| Wanted equipment    | dd.MMMM.yyyy         |
```

I do this but it doesn't work :((((

```
SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
SELECT *
FROM `Tabl№1`
WHERE (`Date` REGEXP '^[0-9]+:[0-9]+$'
OR LOWER(`Date`) LIKE "%сегодня%")
AND `Ads` LIKE (SELECT st.`Zag` FROM `Tabl№2` as st)
```

Comment: What data types do you have for _Date_ columns?

Comment: for example, 18.09.2022

Comment: The regular expression for "Date" works as it should, but for "Ads" it doesn't.

Comment: Type "Date" - text

Comment: It is a really big error to store dates in a string/text/varchar data types. You should *always* use proper data types for your data

Comment: What would you advise to do now and how to write the right request?

Comment: @nacho , can you help in writing a query that will perform the task?